# Conditional instructions in AVX2

Tags: conditional-statements, vectorization, x86-64, instruction-set, avx2

Can you give the list of conditional instructions available in AVX2?
So far I've found the following:

- `_mm256_blendv_`* for selection from `a` and `b` based on mask `c`

Are there something like conditional multiply and conditional add, etc.?

Also if instructions taking `imm8` count (like `_mm256_blend_`*), could you explain how to get that `imm8` after a vector comparision?

Comment: [All AVX2 intrinsics are here](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX2). Is that what you're asking for in the first part of the question? We don't really do "list"-style questions here.

Comment: @CodyGray, I'm using those pages actively, but couldn't find anything more except what I've listed. Perhaps I've missed something. I expect the list to be short, maybe 5 items, maybe no more items. So I think the question isn't too broad. And there is no need to describe what the intrinsics are doing (that can be read from the documentation, once I know how to search for them). Just how to use them in principle like the versions taking `imm8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVX512 introduces optional zero-masking and merge-masking for almost all instructions.

Before that, to do a conditional add, mask one operand (with `vandps` or `vandnps` for the inverse) *before* the add (instead of `vblendvps` on the result).  This is why packed-compare instructions/intrinsics produce all-zero or all-one elements.

`0.0` is the additive identity element, so adding it is a no-op.  (Except for IEEE semantics of -0.0 and +0.0, I forget how that works exactly).

Masking a constant input instead of blending the result avoids making the critical path longer, for something like conditionally adding `1.0`.

---

Conditional multiply is more cumbersome because `0.0` is not the multiplicative identity.  You need to multiply by `1.0` to keep a value unchanged, and you can't easily produce that with an AND or ANDN with a compare result.  You can blendv an input, or you can do the multiply and blendv the output.

The alternative to blendv is at least 3 booleans, like AND/ANDN/OR, but that's usually not worth it.  Although note that Haswell runs `vblendvps` and `vpblendvb` as 2 uops for port 5, so it's a potential bottleneck compared to using integer booleans that can run on any port.  Skylake runs them `vblendvps` as 2 uops for any port.  It could make sense to do something to avoid having a blendv on the critical path, though.

**Masking an input operand or blending the result is generally how you do branchless SIMD conditionals.**

BLENDV is usually at least 2 uops, so it's slower than an AND.

Immediate blends are much more efficient, but you can't use them, because **the `imm8` blend control has to be a compile-time constant** embedded into the instruction's machine code.  That's what *immediate* means in an assembly-language context.

Answer (score 3):

Intel Intrinsics Guide suggests gather, load and store operating with a mask. The immediate imm8 in blend_epi16 is not programmable unless self-modifying code or a jump table is considered an option. It's still possible to derive using pext from BMI2 to compact half of odd positioned bits from the result of movemask -- one gets 32 independent mask bits from movemask in AVX2, but blend_epi16 uses each bit to control four bytes--or one 16-bit variable in each bank.